# Numbers upon each other css design like 1/1, 1/2

Tags: html, css

Looking for this kind of design as in image but not able to get it.
[image]

```css
.bottom {
      font-size: 2.5em;
      font-family: newparisreg;
      color: #a9aaac;
      letter-spacing: -4px;
    }
    .Slash {
      color: rgba(167, 175, 179, 0.5);
      font-family: "newparisreg";
      font-size: 4em;
      letter-spacing: -4px;
    }
    
    .top {
      font-size: 2.5em;
      font-family: Roboto;
      vertical-align: top !important;
      letter-spacing: -4px;
      color: #000;
    }
```

```html
  <span className="top">1</span><span
                        className="Slash">/</span><span
                        className="bottom">3</span></div>
```

Comment: Replace `className` with just `class` and your styling will start to take place. See answer below for smaller numbers. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/sup) for info on superscripting.

Comment: actually classname is equal to class in react to its ok. i am looking for css part.

Comment: Yeah, I saw react code after this, and the classes are made the same way (I don't have experience with react). But that means you have another problem - maybe with applying these classes, because this css is fine for the results you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Did this with one element harnessing the power of pseudo elements and the `content` attribute.

```css
.fraction{
  font-size:3em;
}

.fraction:before{
  content:attr(data-nom);
  vertical-align:super;
  font-size:.5em;
}

.fraction:after{
  content:attr(data-dem);
  vertical-align:middle;
  font-size:.5em;
}
```

```html
<span class="fraction" data-nom="1" data-dem="3">/</span>
```